VPS not booting and help interpreting lsbk
I have a VPS that went offline. Support were useless but suggested it is stuck in a boot loop.
I have managed to spin up rescue mode and login via SSH.
When i run list block devices this is all i get:
"NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   7:0    0 526.5M  1 loop /usr/lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs

df -h gives:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             15G     0   15G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G  8.5M  3.0G   1% /run
/dev/loop0      683M  683M     0 100% /run/live/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
tmpfs            15G  3.9M   15G   1% /run/live/overlay
overlay          15G  3.9M   15G   1% /
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            15G     0   15G   0% /tmp
tmpfs           3.0G  4.0K  3.0G   1% /run/user/0

I am expecting to see the usual partitions /dev/sda etc.
What does this mean or suggest ?
